# Is it true that Ryanair flies without fuel reserves?

Tags: airline-operations, emergency, fuel, ryanair

Is it true that Ryanair flies without any fuel reserves so they get priority to land?

I was told that they declare an emergency for landing because of low fuel levels, that is why they always arrive on time. A pilot friend of a friend told me that, but I am not sure... I used to fly with that company because it was cheap, but now I changed my mind.

Comment: Absolute nonsense.  You would be better asking on Sceptics.SE or snopes.com.  Several years ago, they had a few emergencies close together but the regulatory bodies do what they do and ordered them to  review their policies, which they did.  If they did this as a matter of course, they would be closed down.

Comment: The FAA would have a field day with them if they declared emergencies for every landing just to get priority. There are reserve requirements and they **must** land with them or face regulatory action.

Comment: This group is what I was looking for!

Comment: In all jurisdictions in which Ryanair fly, the minimum amount of fuel they must calculate and carry is mandated by law. It is not for Ryanair to decide. They may carry more, but that's a matter of company ops. EU-OPS covers most of their operations  - "The operator shall establish a fuel policy for the purpose of flight planning and in-flight replanning to ensure that every flight carries sufficient fuel for the planned operation and reserves to cover deviations from the planned operation. The fuel policy and any change to it require prior approval by the competent authority""

Comment: No.  It's illegal under federal regulations.  If a RyanAir pilot is doing that knowingly on a common carriage flight or otherwise, the FAA should revoke his pilot certificate.   If it is an unwritten company policy of RyanAir which is habitually employed in their operation, they should have their air carrier certificate revoked.  That is very dangerous.

Comment: @CarloFelicione Ryan Air don't operate under the jurisdiction of the FAA, though. I'm not sure why people keep mentioning the FAA

Comment: BTW, there are plenty of reasons not to fly Ryanair.  Safety is not one of them. They have only had one hull loss incident, caused by a bird strike and no accidents or fatalities.  Indeed, all major airlines are equally safe from a statistics point of view.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. It is indeed about aviation, but is more about hearsay than an actual question. If the site starts to accept these questions, then it may be used as a fact checker for frivolous purpose. You may ask if there are regulations in Europe about fuel reserves, and what happens if an operator doesn't comply with them.

Comment: Regarding the discussion of jurisdiction, it depends on which of the two similarly named companies are in question. [Ryan Air Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Air_Services) indeed operates under FAA jurisdiction. However, the more likely candidate for this question, [Ryanair Ltd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryanair) is not generally subject to FAA jurisdiction. The former is well known in certain parts of the US, while the latter is well known in much of Europe and worldwide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are most [likely looking at articles like this one](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2205314/Ryanair-courting-disaster-flying-planes-near-fuel-tanks-cut-costs.html) which are not exactly true. There was/is an investigation going on after [3 Ryanair pilots diverted to spain due to weather](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-19267153), an unlikely coincidence at best.

Its a bit dated but you can [find the Ryanair fuel policy here (from their own site)](https://www.ryanair.com/doc/news/2012/mol-mad-23-aug-2012.pdf). Like all airlines they need to carry reserves the [FAA regulates this under 121.639](http://www.flightsimaviation.com/data/FARS/part_121-639.html) and Im sure there is an equal EASA reg. Now airlines are free to exceed this fuel minimum and I am sure many do as a matter of airline regulations but they are also free to run up against the lower limit of it if they please. If it is beneficial to the bottom line to only carry the minimum legally required by authorities a budget airline may do just that. However there is nothing unsafe about this nor illegal, the plane can still make it to a diversion airport if necessary.

For what its worth (at least here in the US) the FAA is going to realize if an airline is constantly declaring a fuel emergency to land.

Comment: In EASA land, a fuel emergency is classified as a "serious incident" and requires an investigation.  So same in Europe.